# Can I change the class of my HTML grid object based off of the outcome of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a grid of boxes, where those boxes change color depending on the contents of a JSON file. I have written some JavaScript that outputs a string saying what each box's color should be. However, I don't know how to translate that into the actual color of the boxes. I know I could give each box an individual id, but there are over 300 boxes and that would be a LOT of duplicate code. Currently, my (very simple) code looks like this:

```
if (parsedJSON[i]['status'] === "Finished") {
    alert("Green");
} else if (parsedJSON[i]['status'] === "Failed") {
    alert("Red");
} else {
    alert("Orange");
}
```

An example of one of the boxes is:

```
.timed-out-test-box {
    background-color: darkorange;
}
<div class=timed-out-test-box></div>
```

Any advice on how I could actually make the boxes have color instead of just alerting the color?

I am using vanilla JS, and the boxes are not dynamic.

Comment: Are you adding the boxes dynamically or is it just the color that is being updated? Can you share a subset of your problem maybe with 5 boxes and the JSON in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to show how you are approaching your use case?

Comment: Does this example solve your problem https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/xxbqXaZ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the boxes ready, then all you need to do is to add a CSS class to said boxes based on the `status` of your `parsedJSON`. Here is a working example:

```js
// Change status to your parsedJSON's logic
let status = ['Finished', 'Failed', 'Something Else']
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div.box')
let i = 0
for (box of boxes) {
  let newClass = ''

  // This is a dummy logical checking to change colours based on status
  if (status[i % 3] == 'Finished')
    newClass = 'green'
  else if (status[i % 3] == 'Failed')
    newClass = 'red'
  else
    newClass = 'orange'

  box.classList.add(newClass)
  i++
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.box.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.box.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.box.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
```

Basically, just add a class based on a `status`. However, if the `box`es are created automatically, simply create the elements like so (of course changing it to fit your `parsedJSON`'s needs):

```
let status = ['Finished', 'Failed', 'Something Else']
let body = document.querySelector('body')
let i = 0
for (i; i < 10; i++) {
  let newClass = ''

  if (status[i % 3] == 'Finished')
    newClass = 'green'
  else if (status[i % 3] == 'Failed')
    newClass = 'red'
  else
    newClass = 'orange'


  let newBoxDiv = document.createElement('div')
  newBoxDiv.classList.add('box', newClass)
  body.appendChild(newBoxDiv)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element and apply the class to it. the way i would do it to make a class for each color ( since you only have three) and apply the class to the element.

this will work if you are using jquery.

**JS**

```
function create_colored_box(color){
   return `<div class="timed-out-test-box ${color}" ></div>`
}

let box = null
if (parsedJSON[i]['status'] === "Finished") {
    box = create_colored_box('green')
} else if (parsedJSON[i]['status'] === "Failed") {
    box = create_colored_box('red')
} else {
    box = create_colored_box('orange')
}

$('body').append(elem);
```

**CSS**

```
//CSS
.timed-out-test-box {
    background-color: darkorange;
}
.timed-out-test-box.red {
   background-color: red
}
.timed-out-test-box.green {
   background-color: red
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using JQuery. I considered using it, but the team decided against it for various reasons. We are using vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of same kind of HTML tags where you want to show alert like this HTML example where you have the same class name on all your entries then

```
<div class="demo-box">
  <input type="text" name="example">
</div>
```

Style

```
.green {
    color: green;
}
.red {
   color: red;
}
.orange {
   color: orange;
}
```

In your javascript try this

```
if (parsedJSON[i]['status'] === "Finished") {
    // alert("Green");
    $('.demo-box').html('<label class="green">Green Time</label>');
} else if (parsedJSON[i]['status'] === "Failed") {
    // alert("Red");
    $('.demo-box').html('<label class="red">Red Time</label>');
} else {
    //alert("Orange");
    $('.demo-box').html('<label class="orange">Orange Time</label>')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On the assumption that you are creating the boxes dynamically, you can assign "parsedJSON[i]['status']" as a class to the respective boxes and in the css you can have the value set to these classes. Check Eg below.

Your html will look like :

```
<div class="finished"></div>
<div class="failed"></div>
```

Your css :

```
.finished{
background-color:green;
```

}

```
.failed{
   background-color:red;
}
```

Hope this helps!